# Pagination doesn't work with DataTables 1.10.7 / 1.10.11

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pagination, datatables

I'm trying to enable server-side processing for data-tables and searching/sorting/chaning amount of rows work, everything except pagination

The setup for datatables is like this:

```
$('[data-table]').each(function() {
    var url = $(this).data("table");
    $(this).DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            url: url,
            type: 'POST'
        }
    });
})
```

Server side, the response looks like this:

```
{
    data: […]
    draw: "12"
    recordsFiltered: 10
    recordsTotal: "208"
}
```

This is the result:
[image: No pagination]

And the funny thing is, if I ommit `recordsFiltered` and `recordsTotal` pagination work (kinda, last dosent work, but the rest does)... check these images:

[image: Pagination without total]

Comment: In your images I dont see more than 10 rows at the bottom.Maybe not enough rows to paginate through?

Comment: I need to count the items sent back before limiting to 10 items :/  Thanks, if you write up an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"recordsTotal" and "recordsFiltered" should be the same value. So, if you have 160 total records in your table or query, yo should set the same value to the "recordsFiltered" parameter.

This is a common misunderstanding, according to the docs. What the docs says and i think we all understand is that we should filter the records and set the "recordsFiltered" this count.

"Total records, after filtering (i.e. the total number of records after filtering has been applied - not just the number of records being returned for this page of data)."

Answer (score 2):

You only have 10 rows coming so no pagination with just 1 page.